# Animating a qt3d rotation around a specific axis

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, qml, qt3d

I am trying to animate an object in Qt3D to rotate around a specific axis (not the origin) while performing other transformations (e.g. scaling and translating).

The following code rotates the object as I want it but without animation yet.

```
QMatrix4x4 mat = QMatrix4x4();
mat.scale(10);
mat.translate(QVector3D(-1.023, 0.836, -0.651));
mat.rotate(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(0,1,0), -20));
mat.translate(-QVector3D(-1.023, 0.836, -0.651));
//scaling here after rotating/translating shifts the rotation back to be around the origin (??)

Qt3DCore::QTransform *transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(root);
transform->setMatrix(mat);
//...
entity->addComponent(transform);   //the entity of the object i am animating
```

I did not manage to incorporate a QPropertyAnimation as I desire with this code. Only animating the rotationY property does not let me include the rotation origin, so it rotates around the wrong axis. And animating the matrix property produces the end result but rotates in a way that is not desired/realistic in my scenario. So how can I animate this rotation to rotate around a given axis?

EDIT: There is a QML equivalent to what I want. There, you can specify the origin of the rotation and just animate the angle values:

```
Rotation3D{
  id: doorRotation
  angle: 0
  axis: Qt.vector3d(0,1,0)
  origin: Qt.vector3d(-1.023, 0.836, -0.651)
}

NumberAnimation {target: doorRotation; property: "angle"; from: 0; to: -20; duration: 500}
```

How can I do this in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible to use the [Qt 3D: Simple C++ Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-simple-cpp-example.html) to obtain what it is looked for by simply modifying the `updateMatrix()` method in `orbittransformcontroller.cpp`:

```
void OrbitTransformController::updateMatrix()
{
    m_matrix.setToIdentity();
    // Move to the origin point of the rotation
    m_matrix.translate(40, 0.0f, -200);
    // Infinite 360° rotation
    m_matrix.rotate(m_angle, QVector3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    // Radius of the rotation
    m_matrix.translate(m_radius, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_target->setMatrix(m_matrix);
}
```

**Note:** It is easier to change the torus into a small sphere to observe the rotation.

---

EDIT from question asker: This idea is indeed a very good way of solving the problem! To apply it specifically to my scenario the `updateMatrix()` function has to look like this:

```
void OrbitTransformController::updateMatrix()
{
    //take the existing matrix to not lose any previous transformations
    m_matrix = m_target->matrix();
    // Move to the origin point of the rotation, _rotationOrigin would be a member variable
    m_matrix.translate(_rotationOrigin);
    // rotate (around the y axis)
    m_matrix.rotate(m_angle, QVector3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    // translate back
    m_matrix.translate(-_rotationOrigin);
    m_target->setMatrix(m_matrix);
}
```

I have made `_rotationOrigin` also a property in the controller class, which can then be set externally to a different value for each controller.

Comment: The second translation should be the negative vector of the first one for it to work.

Comment: To complete the answer: I also added two additional properties to the controller: `_rotationPoint` and `_rotationVector` that I can set externally to make the controller be animatable around an arbitrary rotation point and vector.

Comment: @Mariam Should the second translation be the negative vector of the first one in your case or even in the [Qt 3D: Simple C++ Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-simple-cpp-example.html)? It seemed to work but I'm far to be an expert in 3D :)

Comment: in my case it should be the negative vector, yes. that's how you rotate around a different axis: translate to the rotation point, rotate, translate back where you came from. In the example it is different because they had a different aim. But thanks a lot either way, your simple idea was enough for me to develop this further to fit my case! I can edit your answer with the corrections.

Comment: OK, thank you for the explanation :) You can edit my answer maybe, I don't know, by adding a second part with the modification corresponding to the real answer to the problem and by letting the first part for a more general answer to the problem.